# Display php file contents

Tags: php, vbscript

I am calling php file from vbscript.
this is my sample php file,

**sample.php:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

this is my sample vbscript file,

**sample.vbs:**

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f D:\JSON\hello.php", 0
```

I am executing vbscript through command prompt like this,
`cscript sample.vbs`.

I am not getting any error message also. but I have to display `Hello World` as output.

Comment: Ok, and what output do you have now?

Comment: You want to retrieve output use `Exec()` and check the `StdOut` stream. See [Differences between Run and Exec (VBScript)](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/507798/Differences-between-Run-and-Exec-VBScript)

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Now I am not getting any output. Vbscript will execute and exits.